# logic hook fires only when $bean->status changes

Tags: php, hook, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to implement a Sugar Logic Hook that fires when invoice status change to 'Validated'.
This my logic hook :

```
<?php
$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_save'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(1, 'status invoices Changes', '/var/www/html/suitecrm/modules/AOS_Invoices/AOS_LogicHooks.php','AOS_LogicHooks', 'statusInvoicesChanges'); 
?>
```

This is my action class:

```
<?php class AOS_LogicHooks {
 public function statusInvoicesChanges (SugarBean $bean, $event, $arguments){
if($bean->status == 'Validated' && $bean->fetched_row->status <> $bean->status){ 
$GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Status has been changed");
}}}
?>
```

What do I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake we all do, fetched row is an Array so you cannot access the content as a property.

I just tested this and works fine! take a look:

```
<?php 

class AOS_LogicHooks
{
  public function statusInvoicesChanges(SugarBean $bean, $event, $arguments)
  {
    if ($bean->status == 'Validated' && !empty($bean->fetched_row) && $bean->fetched_row['status'] <> $bean->status) {
      $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Status has been changed");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know but i don't have yet the 15 reputation :)